# Searching are not working properly in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure for searching with paging but the search is not working properly. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in this stored procedure?

```
ALTER PRocedure [dbo].[uspGetAddressByClientAndCode]        
   @PageIndex INT = 1,        
   @PageSize INT = 10,        
   @ClientId int,        
   @clientName varchar(40)= null,        
   @Code varchar(2)=null,         
   @RecordCount INT OUTPUT        
AS        
BEGIN        
   SET NOCOUNT ON;        

   SELECT * FROM (      
       SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AD.[CLIENTID] DESC) AS RowNumber
       ,AD.[NAME]        
       ,AD.[ADDR]        
       ,AD.[CITY]        
       ,AD.[STPROV]        
       ,AD.[ZIPPOSTAL]        
       ,AD.[COUNTRY]        
       ,AD.[ZONE]         
       ,AD.[CLIENTID]        
       ,CL.BCLIENT         
       ,AD.ADDRESSID        
   FROM 
       [Address] Ad         
   INNER JOIN 
       client CL ON CL.CLIENTID = AD.[CLIENTID]         
   WHERE             
       AD.CLIENTID = @ClientId         
        AND (AD.NAME IS NULL OR AD.NAME Like  @clientName +'%')         
        AND (AD.code IS NULL OR AD.code = @Code)
 ) As PageTable           
 WHERE 
    RowNumber BETWEEN (@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND (((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1        
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Even it's not clear why this stored procedure aren't working properly I *suppose* you have to change the WHERE clause like this:

```
   WHERE             
       AD.CLIENTID = @ClientId         
        AND (@clientName IS NULL OR AD.NAME Like  @clientName +'%')         
        AND (@Code IS NULL OR AD.code = @Code)
```

Comment: i used that before but not get  result :(

Comment: Did you tried to execute only the derived table (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE) to see if this query returns results ? Maybe the page number used to call the SP was too high and the SP didn't returned any results because of this reason.